# List of all folders and folders inside them for Dropbox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, dropbox

Im adding a "move to folder" functionality to my app with dropbox support. Im trying to get all folders, and subfolders throughout the whole users dropbox. Heres the code i have right now that if logged, has the right order but is backwards

```
-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

    if (allFolders == nil) {
        allFolders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [allFolders addObject:@"/"];
    }

    for (DBMetadata *fileMetadata in metadata.contents) {

        if ([fileMetadata isDirectory]) {
            NSArray *filePathComponents = [fileMetadata.path pathComponents];
            NSString *inFolder = [filePathComponents objectAtIndex:[filePathComponents count]-2];
            NSLog(@"file is in folder %@",inFolder);
            [allFolders insertObject:fileMetadata.filename atIndex:[allFolders indexOfObject:inFolder]];
            if ([metadata.contents count] > 0) [[self restClient] loadMetadata:fileMetadata.path];

        }

    }

}
```

the issue with this is my `hViewFoldersViewController` also has to show all folders for the documents directory for the app, and i use a custom `NSObject` called Folder Item which stores all items path, name, and indent level for the table. if i use this method, i cannot get the path because al lFolders in inside the dropbox helper class, i can move it to the `viewcontroller` but the thing that is confusing me is getting the `objectAtIndex`. if i leave it to just adding objects, it will show all first level folders, then second, then third. i want it so if in dropbox you have a folder called "test 1" and then test 1 contained "test 2", then it shows test 1, then with more indent the test 2 folder and then other first directory folders.  and if i use my FolderItem in the array i cannot find the `objectAtIndex`. How can i get the index of the folders i need to insert then?

Comment: FYI - The Dropbox page https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/bestpractice states that you shouldn't get a recursive listing of a user's Dropbox files.

Comment: An app i use does it, and it would be annoying for a user to have to go through all folders to finally find the right folder. their probably just saying dont try to get every single file in the whole dropbox, im just getting folders so if they have a folder called "books" and then a subdirectory called "PDFS" they dont have to go through 2 folders, instead its on 1 page. easier.

Comment: Consider that you are doing a network call for every single directory. What is the user has dozens of directories? Why make the user wait while you do a network call for each one? Consider that in OS X, when you save a file, the user has to manually traverse the directory structure. Save time and bandwidth and consider letting the user navigate as need instead of preloading everything.

Comment: Im doing it like this now. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are building a simple list of filenames. You need to build a tree structure. One way is to create an array of dictionaries. Each element in the array is a dictionary. The dictionary contains the filename and an array of its subdirectories.

As the `restClient:loadedMetadata:` method is called, you need to look at the metadata to determine the parent directory. Use this to find the correct spot in your tree structure so you can fill in the subdirectory array at the proper node in the tree.

Comment: thanks, i was trying to go to each file and get the directory above. makes more sense to get the directory when loading the metadata so i dont have to each file.